# Static member has to be initialized?

Tags: c++, class, static-members

The code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    static int id_;

public:
    static void setId(int id) {
        id_ = id;
    }
    static int getId() {
        return id_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A::setId(10);
    cout << A::getId() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it in *Xcode*, *Mac OS*, there's an error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "A::id_", referenced from:
      A::setId(int) in main.o
      A::getId() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I add the line:

```
int A::id_ = 10;
```

before the `main()`. Then, everything is fine. What's the reason with it?

Comment: Because that's how static members are declared.

Comment: @0x499602D2: **defined**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables need to be *declared* and *defined* and the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `9.4.2` *Static data members* says:

> The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a definition [...]

so it must be *defined*, which is why you need to add:

```
int A::id_ = 10;
```

and to see this more clearly, we see that:

```
int A::id_ ;
```

is sufficient, we don't have to initialize `A::id_` just *define* it.

You may also want to read this previous thread: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration).

As Steve points out when you move to using *header* files you will need to [define your variable in the cpp file](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145299/why-the-static-data-members-have-to-be-defined-outside-the-class-separately-in-c) since you do not want more than one definition.

Comment: And if you move your class to a header file, as will happen if your project gets bigger, the definition has to be in a .cpp.

Answer (score 2):

Once a class object is made certain compilers do not allow creation of static variables without initialization.